# JS - Calculate price depending on span/div fields

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have a form, where a user can select between different options inside a few dropdown fields. Depending on the user selection, the values will be displayed inside a span field next to the dropdown field.

Now I would like to count all those values inside the span fields, so that I can display a total amount at the end of the form before it will be submitted.

Here is a part of my form:

```
<form name='formname_form' action='./index.php' method='post' class='formname-form' id='formname-form'>
<div class="row" id='save_prices'>
    <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <label class="form-icon">
                <figure>
                    <img src="../assets/images/symbol-1.png" alt="/">
                </figure>
            </label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="field_a" id="field_a" onchange="CalcDiscount()">
                    <option value="0,00">Option A?</option>
                    <option value="6,17">Yes</option>
                    <option value="0,00">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="amount-wrap-3">
                <span>&euro; <span id='field_a_price' class='prices'></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <label class="form-icon">
                <figure>
                    <img src="../assets/images/symbol-2.png" alt="/">
                </figure>
            </label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="field_b" id="field_b" onchange="CalcDiscount()">
                    <option value="0,00">Option B</option>
                    <option value="17,50">Yes</option>
                    <option value="0,00">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="amount-wrap-3">
                <span>&euro; <span id='field_b_price' class='prices'></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-sm-12">
        <div class="total-amount">
            Total Price
            <div class='price'><span id='total_price' class="total_price"></span> &euro;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input name='submit' type='submit' id='submit' value='Save' class='btn btn-form-indiv'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is my javascript part:

```
<script>
    // Get references to the objects you need (<select> and <span>)
    var field_a = document.getElementById('field_a');
    var field_a_price = document.getElementById('field_a_price');

    var field_b = document.getElementById('field_b');
    var field_b_price = document.getElementById('field_b_price');

    // When the list value changes, set the innerHTML of the <span>
    field_a.onchange = function() {
        field_a_price.innerHTML = this.value;
    };

    field_b.onchange = function() {
        field_b_price.innerHTML = this.value;
    };

    var priceList = $('#save_prices').find('.prices');
    var totalPrice = 0;

    $.each(priceList, function(i, price){
        totalPrice += parseInt($(price).text())
    });

    $('.total_price').text(totalPrice);

</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong? The value inside my span with the class `total_price` stays always `0`. I assume that is has something to do with my onChange methods that I am using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The total from the 2 select boxes are not appearing in the Total Price area.

**Solution**

Create a function and call it to fire off on the onchange event when a new value is selected in the selection boxes.

**Example**

```
  // Get references to the objects you need (<select> and <span>)
    var field_a = document.getElementById('field_a');
    var field_a_price = document.getElementById('field_a_price');

    var field_b = document.getElementById('field_b');
    var field_b_price = document.getElementById('field_b_price');

    // When the list value changes, set the innerHTML of the <span>
    field_a.onchange = function() {
        field_a_price.innerHTML = this.value;
        // Calling new function
        updateTotal();
    };

    field_b.onchange = function() {
        field_b_price.innerHTML = this.value;
        // Calling new function
        updateTotal();
    };

  // New function
  function updateTotal() {
    var p = $('.prices').map(function () { return $(this).text(); }).get();
    var totalPrice = 0;
    $.each(p, function( index, value ) {
      totalPrice = totalPrice + value;
      $('.total_price').text(totalPrice);
    });
  }
```

**Summary**

I am not sure what you are attempting to do with the values considering they have commas.

To directly address your question, when your code is ran the reason the values are always empty is because all the code only runs on page load. When you change the selection box values only the code in the `onchange` was being ran. By adding a function that is called each time a selection is made we can populate the array from the class list returned with JQuery.